# Which Jackson API helps to convert Scala object into JSON object. I have used it for Java to JSON conversion

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I want to use Jackson API to convert scala object to json. I have used the Jackson API 1.9.13 (jackson-core-asl, jackson-mapper-asl jars) to convert java object to json and vice versa. However I am not able to find jars to convert from scala object to json. Does any one have idea about this? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I created a Java class and wrote a function to build JSON using Jackson API 1.9.13. The function returns the Json String. 
Then created the object in Scala and called the Java-To-Json conversion function in the Java class. It worked just fine.